# How to add entries in existing set in hibernate for ManyToMany relationship?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have User.java class as follow

```
@Entity
@Table (name="users")
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="userId")
    private int userId;

    @Column(name="userName")
    @NaturalId
    private String userName;

    @JsonProperty( value = "password", access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name="firstName")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="lastName")
    private String lastName;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private UserRole userRole;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name="user_followings",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="userId"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="followingId"))
    private Set<User> followings = new HashSet<>();

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="followings")
    private Set<User> followers = new HashSet<>();

   // getters and setters

   @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(userName);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        User other = (User) obj;
        return Objects.equals(userName, other.getUserName());
    }
}
```

I want to add followings for users anytime the user wants to add another user. The first time when I tried to add followings for the user., it is getting added in the followings list but after that, it is throwing an error stating that *"A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.me.pojo.User#2]"*. My follow method is as follows. What thing am I missing?

```
    public void follow(User user, String followingId) throws UserException {
        try {
            begin();
            User followingUser = getUserFromId(followingId);
            if (followingUser.equals(user)) {
                throw new HibernateException("Same User");
            }

            Set<User> followings = user.getFollowings();
            if(!followings.contains(followingUser)) {
                followings.add(followingUser);
                user.setFollowings(followings);
                getSession().update(user);
            }
            commit();
            close();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            rollback();
            throw new UserException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is no need to call update(). user is a managed entity. Every change you make is transparently and automatically saved at the end of the transaction.

Comment: If I don't call update() then It is not getting persisted to MySQL

Comment: Then your session management and/or your transaction management is wrong.

Comment: What things do I need to consider for session and transaction management?

Comment: Okay, I have solved the problem..The User object which I was getting as a parameter was belonged to a different session. There was some problem with my session management. Thanks for the guidance.